# load Scene with Script but it turns Black

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've done it so far that when my player dies the level is restarted and I've written everything in the script but when I try it and the scene is reloaded everything is somehow extremely dark compared to before, although all settings from the camera etc. are the same and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug

my Script:

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject enemyPrefab;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    SpawnEnemy();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    RestartGame();
}

void RestartGame()
{
    if(GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().playerHealth <= 0)
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your script into the post, we can't tell you the issue with your code without seeing it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bake your lighting inside your scene. Here are instructions on how:

1. Head to Window > Rendering > Lighting
   [image]
2. Press Generate Lighting (Make sure Auto Generate is unselected)

[image]

[Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1264278/unity-5-directional-light-problem-please-help.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some trouble. But I'm not going to fix rotation issues. But here your working sample:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject enemyPrefab;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    GameObject player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    SpawnEnemy();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    RestartGame();
}

bool navigated = false;
void RestartGame()
{
   if (!navigated)
   {
      if(GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().playerHealth <= 0)
      {
        navigated = true;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);        
      }
    }
}
}
```